# POSTing data to an SharePoint 2010 list with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, sharepoint-2010, ngresource

Long story short: I've been trying to push data back to a list on our SP2010 implementation with no luck. The saga started with doing it with straight ajax, which worked, then I tried via factory function with the ngResource addon. That was a fail... the least I could get it to fail was getting this error as a response back:

```
"error": {
  "code": "", "message": {
    "lang": "en-US", "value": "Query options $expand, $filter, $orderby, $inlinecount, $skip and $top cannot be applied to the requested resource."
    }
  }
```

Needless to say, I cried, when I tried the nearly similar same attempt via the $http function, ala:

```
$http({
            method: "MERGE",
            url: URL + "?$filter=Idir%20eq%20" + "'" + CurrentUser.UserName + "'",
            data: {'Title': null, 'Vote': '2', 'Idir': 'test'},
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }} ).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('you did it, billy');
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                //error
        });
```

I got the same error... this looks like a SharePoint rest fail, to me... how else could I approach this problem (while keeping in mind I can only get back 1000 records per request because SharePoint is terrible)?

It seems like any kind of $filter being passed in to narrow down my criteria ends up blowing everything up. How am I going to do a SQL-type-SELECT statement without actually being able to do one‽ ;_;

**Many thanks in advance!**

/Roman

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the similar problems when I migrated a SharePoint app to Angular and even though I resolved it by a custom REST Api because of some complexities of my SharePoint application you can use camelot in yours, I think it will help you. Here is the link to this framework:

http://camelotjson.codeplex.com/

Comment: Oh lord, that looks incredible... let me throw one painful caveat in: I don't have farm access, I can only come at this as a reasonably astute power-end-user. Sigh (our company admin are draconian and slow to act, and usually unwilling).

Comment: Been there :D... In my case btw angular improved the user experience and navigation speed a lot.

Comment: It's a horrific place to be, as you know! Do you have any other suggestions as to how to code around this sticky-seeming issue?